# how to ng-include an svg with webpack

Tags: angularjs, svg, webpack

I include my svg using

```
<div ng-include="'src/assets/arrowdown.svg'"></div>
```

This works correctly when using npm run dev with that:

```
webpack-dev-server --https --host 0.0.0.0
```

But when I use a build, the svg that has been included using ng-include are not processed.

With other svg, used as classic resource, they are read at build time, their name is changed to handle versionning and output look like this:

```
background: url(//assets.mysite.com/build/4341cb2ee439f765105fb3258df4048c.svg) 50% no-repeat
```

When using ng-include the final build looks like this:

```
GET https://assets.mysite.com/src/assets/img/arrowdown.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

So the svg is not read by the loader

What should I do to make webpack detect the ng-include and extract the svg in the resources ?

Thanks

Using angularjs 1.5.5 with webpack 1.13.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different method, I finally had something that work.

Just putting this here in case someone has no better idea.

I created a simple service that contains the svg inline.

Loading a resource like this:

```
<span ng-include="loadSvgResource('count')"></span>
```

In the controller:

```
this.loadSvgResource = function(d) {
    return svgResourceService[d];
};
```

The service contains the inline svg:

```
this.count= "data:image/svg+xml,...";
```

It is not much but it's honest work that works with my current constraints.